# Adding information to a compressed file and compressing the output

Tags: python, performance, compression, bioinformatics

I wrote this script for adding information to a compressed file and compressing the output:

```
#!/bin/env python3

import argparse
from Bio.bgzf import BgzfWriter
import gzip
import sys

def main():

    args = parse_args()

#    with BgzfWriter(args.out, 'wb') as fd_out:
    with gzip.open(args.out, 'wt') as fd_out:
        for i_vcf, vcf in enumerate(args.vcf):
            with gzip.open(vcf, 'rt') as fd_vcf:
                ## loop metadata lines and header line
                for line in fd_vcf:
                    ## end of metadata lines
                    if line[0:2] != '##':
                        ## print header line
                        print(line, end='', file=fd_out)
                        ## break loop at the header line
                        break
                    if i_vcf == 0:
                        ## print metadata line
                        print(line, end='', file=fd_out)
                ## loop records
                for line in fd_vcf:
                    l = line.rstrip().split('\t')
                    s = '\t'.join(l[:9])+':GL'
                    i_PL = l[8].split(':').index('PL')
                    print(s, sep='\t', file=fd_out, end='\t')
                    for i_GT in range(9, len(l)):
                        s_PL = l[i_GT].split(':')[i_PL]
                        if s_PL == '.':
                            s_GL = '.'
                        else:
#                            l_probs = [
#                                pow(10, -int(log10likelihood)/10) for log10likelihood in s_PL.split(',')]
#                            sum_prob = sum(l_probs)
#                            s_GL = ','.join(map(str, (round(prob/sum_prob, 4) for prob in l_probs)))
                            s_GL = ','.join(str(-float(PL)/10) for PL in s_PL.split(','))
                            print(':'.join((l[i_GT], s_GL)), end='\t', file=fd_out)
                    print(file=fd_out)

    return


def parse_args():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--vcf', nargs = '+')
    parser.add_argument('--out', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is an [example](ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/technical/working/20130624_phase3_chr20/bi/ALL.chr20.broad_assembly.20130502.snps_indels.low_coverage.genotypes.vcf.gz) of an input file:

```
fileformat=VCFv4.1
##FILTER=<ID=LowQual,Description="Low quality">
##FILTER=<ID=VQSRTrancheINDEL99.00to99.50,Description="Truth sensitivity tranche level for INDEL model at VQS Lod: -1.0597 <= x < 0.1687">
##FILTER=<ID=VQSRTrancheINDEL99.50to99.90,Description="Truth sensitivity tranche level for INDEL model at VQS Lod: -5.8589 <= x < -1.0597">
##FILTER=<ID=VQSRTrancheINDEL99.90to99.95,Description="Truth sensitivity tranche level for INDEL model at VQS Lod: -6.5565 <= x < -5.8589">
##FILTER=<ID=VQSRTrancheINDEL99.95to100.00+,Description="Truth sensitivity tranche level for INDEL model at VQS Lod < -70.77">
##FILTER=<ID=VQSRTrancheINDEL99.95to100.00,Description="Truth sensitivity tranche level for INDEL model at VQS Lod: -70.77 <= x < -6.5565">
##FILTER=<ID=VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to99.95,Description="Truth sensitivity tranche level for SNP model at VQS Lod: -96.2455 <= x < -14.2763">
##FILTER=<ID=VQSRTrancheSNP99.95to100.00+,Description="Truth sensitivity tranche level for SNP model at VQS Lod < -437.9355">
##FILTER=<ID=VQSRTrancheSNP99.95to100.00,Description="Truth sensitivity tranche level for SNP model at VQS Lod: -437.9355 <= x < -96.2455">
##FORMAT=<ID=AD,Number=.,Type=Integer,Description="Allelic depths for the ref and alt alleles in the order listed">
##FORMAT=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Approximate read depth (reads with MQ=255 or with bad mates are filtered)">
…
```

The `gzip` module seems somewhat slow in 'rt' mode.  Is there any way I can make this run faster? I've run cProfile on it, and after letting it run for ~35 seconds I got this output:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

   967857    4.333    0.000   15.627    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
  1936445    4.534    0.000   11.917    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
     4528    0.049    0.000    9.982    0.002 gzip.py:328(write)
     4527    9.853    0.002    9.853    0.002 {method 'compress' of 'zlib.Compress' objects}
  3950458    7.382    0.000    7.382    0.000 PL2GL.py:42(<genexpr>)
  1986270    2.012    0.000    2.012    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
```

Here is a small input file on which it will work:

```
##foo
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  x1  x2  x3
18  10310   .   A   C,G 9.22    .   bar GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/0:2,1,0:3:6:0,6,55,6,55,55    0/0:11,0,0:12:27:0,27,249,27,249,249    0/0:6,0,0:6:15:0,15,140,15,140,140
```